# UI freezes when using async await

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, asynchronous, async-await

I have troubles to make my UI work using an async method. Here is a part of my code

```
private async void btnDoOutput_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    /* Initiliaze */
    groupBoxConfiguration.IsEnabled = false;

    var progressIndicator = new Progress<int>();
    progressIndicator.ProgressChanged += (s,value) =>
    {
        progressExport.Value = (double)value;
        labelPercentage.Content = "Export in progress : " + value + " %";
    };
    /* do Work */

    switch (something)
    {
        case 1:
            await method(input, output, options, progressIndicator);
            break;
         default: break;
    }

    /* Finalization */  
    groupBoxConfiguration.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

The method is

```
public async static Task<string> method(string input, string output, string options, IProgress<int> progress)
{
    while(something)
    {
        //operations on input and output

        if (progress != null)
        {
            progress.Report(percentage);
        }
    }
}
```

When I click on my button, the UI freezes, the groupBox is still enabled, the progress is not shown until the end.

Comment: That can't be all of your code, because your method signature is invalid.  `method` doesn't return anything, yet it is `Task<string>`.  Async / await is not "magically make my code async".  It is "make this code, that is already async, easier to work with."  I don't see anything actually asynchronous happening in your code.

Comment: You'll probably get a lot out of this MSDN link on enabling progress reporting and cancellation in async methods: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis.aspx

Comment: i think you need something like `return Task.Factory.StartNew<string>(()=>{while(something){...}})`

Answer (score 2):

I think you are completely misunderstanding how `async` / `await` actually works. All of your code is still running on the UI thread because you don't actually tell it otherwise. This means your `await` on `method` is pointless because it's going to run synchronously anyway.

The purpose of `async`/`await` is to allow the calling code the opportunity to continue processing until it hits part of the code that requires the result of the awaitable task. So in your example, you would need to change your `method` body to actually return an awaitable `Task`

```
public Task method(string input, string output, string options, IProgress<int> progress)
{
    return Task.Run(() => {
        while(something)
        {
            //operations on input and output

           if (progress != null)
           {
               progress.Report(percentage);
           }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: There is no reason whatsoever to call `Invoke` before reporting progress.  The whole *point* of using the `Progress` class is that it manages the task of marshaling to the UI thread on your behalf.  You should also use `Task.Run` rather than `StartNew`.

Comment: @Servy fair enough, I wasn't aware that `Progress` automatically did this. I removed the example anyway it was just bloating the answer unnecessarily.

Comment: Also, all of your comments in `MyMethod` are wrong.  `Calculating...` does *not* take place while `CalcSomething` is running.  The `await` ensures that it won't run until after `CalcSomething` finishes.

Comment: Also, `CalcSomething` shouldn't be `async`.  As it is, it won't compile, as you're already returning a task.  You're also not awaiting anything.

Comment: @Servy The example was all wrong, syntactically & logically (I wasn't in front of an IDE).

Answer (score -2):

First of all please don't use static methods, especially static workers.

I believe the problem is you're still on your UI thread (I'm making some wild assumptions based on the code you've given).  Try using `Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(...)` which should automatically invoke off the UI thread.

Note may need to use the dispatcher and invoke back onto the UI thread to get your Progress bar working.

Comment: The UI thread is synchronous (which is why his is freezing when he performs the work), the TPL will automatically invoke over to a background thread when you start a new Task which will keep your UI responsive.