# What purpose does asynchronous programming solve if using `await` pauses code continuation?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await

Using `async` `await` makes the methods execute on the UI thread by default. I have ran into situations where performing `await` on an expensive operation will result in the UI blocking ([Like this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24286784/ui-freezes-when-using-async-await) )

For example,

```
import asyncio

async def freeze_ui_5_seconds():
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
```

`await`ing this function on the UI thread will freeze the UI for 5 seconds. By utilizing `await` the code will pause and not continue until the `await` method has completed and a value can be returned. My question is, what does this achieve in the end if `await` essentially makes the code synchronous, that is, we will not continue until the `await` method has completed. Using `await` in my mind just retracts the idea of asynchronous programming as we are now "pausing" and "not continuing" until this method has completed and will freeze the UI.

Comment: A simple example is that you can invoke several async function in a row, and they will not wait for the previous ones to finish

Comment: You can create several async tasks that don't wait for each other, but use `asyncio.gather` to wait for all of them to finish. https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather

Comment: This can be solved by coupling the GUI event loop and the async event loop. E. g. for tkinter it is described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895765/use-asyncio-and-tkinter-or-another-gui-lib-together-without-freezing-the-gui.

Comment: @MMZK1526 if I had several async functions using `await`, I would need to wait for one to finish before it moved on.